# How to get a textbox value using selenium webdriver & Java?

Tags: java, selenium

1) I have entered name in "Full Name" text box field.

```
 WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("userId"));
        name.sendKeys("Sekhar");
```

it has entered value in the textbox.

2) I have to validate that "Sekhar" is presented in the textbox. but here the problem is the value entered in the textbox is displaying in watermark
  `logger.info(name.getText());` does not returning a value

because it is displayed in watermark in the textbox.

please help me how to get a watermark text in textbox.

Answer (score 7):

It would depend on what do you mean by watermark and what is the HTML representation of the input element. But, this should be either a `value` attribute:

```
name.getAttribute('value');
```

or could be a `placeholder`:

```
name.getAttribute('placeholder');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('xxxx').style.display='block';");
```

Comment: what its this response about??

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: Some explanation makes the difference between a good and a perfect answer. Please edit your answer and add some context.